# Shrinking the width of a Div and centering the content of the page

Tags: html, css, flexbox, width, centering

I'm trying recreate this photo but I have run into an issue that I'm not so sure how to fix! So I need to shrink the width of the container class but I'm no entirely sure how. I've tried all kinds of different flex box strategies. My question is how can I shrink the width of the container class and how can I move all of the content to the center of the screen like in the photo? (If you expand the snippet to full screen all the content shows in the top left) [image: recreation]
**Here is what I have so far:**

```css
body {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: white;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #5A5A5A;
  color: white;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#clickMe {
  border: 1px solid white;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>List of items</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="header">
    <h1>Products</h1>
    <p>______
      <p>
  </div>
  <div id="appendToMe">
    <div class="boxes">

      <div class="container">
        <p>Hello</p>
        <p>World</p>
        <p>Hello</p>
      </div>

      <div class="container">
        <p>Hello</p>
        <p>World</p>
        <p>Hello</p>
      </div>

      <div class="container">
        <p>Hello</p>
        <p>World</p>
        <p>Hello</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="clickMe">Toggle Dark Mode</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to wrap all your content which you want smaller and centered into another `<div>` element and shrink + center it

CSS Styling would be:

```css
.shrink-container {
    width: 400px; // or any other value you want
    margin: 0 auto; // this is actually centering the container
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: white;
}

.shrink-container {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #5A5A5A;
  color: white;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#clickMe {
  border: 1px solid white;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>List of items</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="shrink-container">
    <div id="header">
      <h1>Products</h1>
      <p>______
        <p>
    </div>
    <div id="appendToMe">
      <div class="boxes">

        <div class="container">
          <p>Hello</p>
          <p>World</p>
          <p>Hello</p>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
          <p>Hello</p>
          <p>World</p>
          <p>Hello</p>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
          <p>Hello</p>
          <p>World</p>
          <p>Hello</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="clickMe">Toggle Dark Mode</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can wrap then inside another div and just give `max-width` & `margin: auto` to it. Which would limit its width and keep it in center.

```css
body {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: white;
}

.container-outer {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #5A5A5A;
  color: white;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#clickMe {
  border: 1px solid white;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>List of items</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-outer">
    <div id="header">
      <h1>Products</h1>
      <p>______
        <p>
    </div>
    <div id="appendToMe">
      <div class="boxes">

        <div class="container">
          <p>Hello</p>
          <p>World</p>
          <p>Hello</p>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
          <p>Hello</p>
          <p>World</p>
          <p>Hello</p>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
          <p>Hello</p>
          <p>World</p>
          <p>Hello</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="clickMe">Toggle Dark Mode</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks this helps a lot. Is there anyway I can move the div to the center of the page regardless of the body size? Because it is only moving to the center of where the  <body> width is if that makes sense.

Comment: Can you show any type of example of what you want to achieve? any drawing/image if possible?